# React-Native Firebase ML Kit Vision Image Labeling not working with iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am trying to use RNFirebase MLKit image labelling in my RN app. It works fine on android, but on iOS i get the following error,

> NativeFirebaseError: [vision/file-not-found] The local file specified does not exist on the device.

The images are taken though `"@react-native-community/cameraroll"` and the ios image path is as follows,

> ph://45983F53-3C96-42D0-9337-C9F681293627/L0/001

The fixes i have tried are,

```
import {utils} from '@react-native-firebase/app';

${utils.FilePath.PICTURES_DIRECTORY}/${
                d[key].node.image.filename
             }
```

```
 'assets-library' +
               '://asset/asset.JPEG?id=' +
               d[key].node.image.uri.substring(5).replace('/L0/001', '') +
               '&ext=JPEG'
```

```
ph-upload://45983F53-3C96-42D0-9337-C9F681293627/L0/001
```

None of the above worked.

The Build versions are,

```
"react-native": "0.62.2".
"@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^1.5.2".
"@react-native-firebase/ml-vision": "^7.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.1.0",
```

Comment: The React-Native Firebase ML Kit is not well maintained, any chance you will use the native ObjC or Swift in your project. We will discuss internally about the support for React-Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using RNFS package, here is how I fixed it, if a better method is available please let me know

use `RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(imagePath,destination,0,0)` to create a temporary file in the temporary files directory `RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath` and use that path for RN-MLKit. once done use `RNFS.unlink(path)` to delete the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

The React-Native Firebase ML Kit is not currently being maintained. We have moved ML Kit's on-device APIs (including the on-device image labeling) out of Firebase. Please check out g.co/mlkit for the new standalone ML Kit. We are currently working on our future plan for the React-Native support in the new standalone ML Kit and would be very interested in hearing from your input on the importance of support React-Native support in the new standalone ML Kit. In the meantime, you can use the ML Kit SDK directly on iOS through Swift or Objective-C APIs.